# Ag grid - processCellCallback for export data does not work Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using `ag-grid` for data grid in `Angularjs` application but it does not work. It does not even throw any error. Below is my export function -

```
exportData: function() {
        var vm = this;
        var params = {
            fileName : vm.pageTitle + '.csv',
            processCellCallback : function(params) { 
            console.log(params.value);
             if (params.value && params.value.toUpperCase) {
                    return params.value.toUpperCase();
                } else {
                    return params.value;
                }
            }
        };
        vm.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);     
    }
```

Below are the versions I am using -

Angular : 1.5.0

Ag-grid : 2.3.5

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ag-grid : 2.3.5

There is your problem... the Docs are constantly updated for the most recent release. You are using 2 year old technology and trying to use the most recent features. Here is the Github repo for your release:

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/tree/2.3.5

You can look through there to find the docs of what is available to you... or you could upgrade to the most recent release.

---

For convenience sake here are the only `params` available to you if you remain on 2.3.5:

- `skipHeader`: Set to true if you don't want to first line to be the column header names.
- `skipGroups`: Set to true to skip headers and footers if grouping. No impact if not grouping.
- `skipFooters`: Set to true to skip footers only if grouping. No impact if not grouping or if not using footers in grouping.
- `fileName`: String to use as the file name. If missing, the file name 'export.csv' will be used.
- `customHeader`: If you want to put some text at the top of the csv file, stick it here.
          You will need to include '\n' at the end, or many '\n' if you want the header to span lines..
- `customFooter`: Same as customHeader, but for the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jarod. I will upgrate the `ag-grid` version.